# Evaluating a line integral when it is not a straight line segment?

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

I'm trying to solve the following line integral:

$$\int_C (2x+1) \, dx + 2y \, dy;$$

$C$ is the curve from $(0,1)$ to $(\pi/2, 0)$ along the curve $y = \cos x$
which would be the upper-right quadrant of a circle's perimeter right?

I assume that I can start with the parametrization of letting $x=t$ and subsequently, $y=\cos(x)=\cos(t)$

$dy=-\sin(t) \, dt$ and $dx=1 \, dt$

Unfortunately, when I substitute this into the integral I get the nasty product of $\cos(t)\sin(t)$ that I have to integrate.
Is my approach to this wrong?
Also I assume the limits of integration would be $0$ to $\pi/2$?

EDIT: Here is my attempt at an answer: $$\int_0^{\pi/2} (2x+1) \, dx + 2y \, dy;$$
Substituting our values for $x, y, dx, dy$:
$$=\int_0^{\pi/2}((2t+1)-2cos(t)sin(t))dt$$
Use the identity $2cos(t)sin(t)=sin(2t)$: 
$$=\int_0^{\pi/2}((2t+1)-sin(2t))dt$$
Integrating yields:
$$=[t^2+t+1/2cos(2t)]$$
Upper bound is $\pi/2$ and lower bound is $0$:
$$=\pi^2/2+\pi/2-1/2-1/2$$
$$=\pi^2/2+\pi/2-1$$

EDIT: Whoops, screwed up as Santiago pointed out. Fixed now.

Comment: $\cos(t)\sin(t)$ can be evaluated using the double angle formula for $\sin$.

Comment: You evaluated your expression at the lower bound of $0$ incorrectly. Also note that you don't need a trig identity to integrate $2\cos t\sin t$, you can instead use the substitution $u=\sin t$.

Comment: Do you mean that I don't have the proper lower bound or what?
EDIT: Nvm I understood you now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that the vector field is conservative. In particular, $$\nabla(x^2+x+y^2)=(2x+1,2y).$$ So the answer must be $$\begin{align}\int_C (2x+1) \, dx + 2y \, dy&=(x^2+x+y^2)\Bigg|_{(0,1)}^{(\pi/2,0)} \\ &=\frac{\pi^2}{4}+\frac{\pi}{2}-1\end{align}$$

Answer (score 0):

Use the fact that $2\sin t\cos t=\sin(2t)$. Then, use the substitution $u=2t$ to evaluate $\int^b_a \sin t\cos tdt$. It is not hard to figure out the values of $a$ and $b$.

Comment: Thanks, I added an attempt at an answer using that identity.